# Defining Primary Key for entity CodeFirst Ef4

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, entity

I want to define a primary key for a POCO entity but i dont want to decorate the entity with primary key attribute i wanna define that from the context class which extend DbContext

i know i should use something like:

```
Entity<Order>().HasKey(x => x.OrderId);
```

but i dont know how to do that in my context class.

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you `DbContext`-class you can override `OnModelCreating` like this

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>.HasKey(x => x.OrderId);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: actually that thrown stackoverflow exception 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

i guess it kept calling it self

Comment: which i find reasonably expected

Comment: now everytime i access the db it gives me :
The model backing the 'DatabaseContext' context has changed since the database was created. Either manually delete/update the database, or call Database.SetInitializer with an IDatabaseInitializer instance. For example, the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges strategy will automatically delete and recreate the database, and optionally seed it with new data.

Comment: got it fixed had to delete database and then let it create it again.

Answer (score -1):

You should create a class that defines your context, and then you have to override the OnModelCreating method.
Try this:

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{
     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasKey(x => x.OrderId);
       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     }
}
```

Comment: its not when your not copying from someone else.